# How to add "Action Points" to Scenekit Game using Gameplaykit or something similar

Tags: ios, swift, logic, scenekit

This is a very common question, and I am not asking for technical details. What I am looking for is an approach or best practice guidance for the following situation:

Imagine a jump and run game entirely made with SceneKit. The game is played by controlling a character running to the right or left side, climbing up walls and jump over obstacles. (it is a 2½-D style game where the character always runs in one direction or it's opposite. Mainly on the x-Axis)

At certain "locations" (on the scene x-axis) I need to implement some specific actions, that should occur as soon as the main character walks, jumps or runs over that specific point.

What I have done so far, is adding simple invisible SCNPlanes with static physics bodies, with the bitmask configured to detect only the contact (no collision). In the physics handler (physics delegate) I can now fetch contact of the objects the character trespasses. Currently I have a large switch-statement to fetch the names of the "Action-Walls" as I call the planes through which the character walks. So, I can trigger whatever specific action that I want to happen at that location.

It is working this way, even quite good, but I wonder if there is a way to add some better "action points" using i.e. Gameplaykit, but I only find information about agents and behaviors or pathfinding.

What I am looking for is some static point, when trespassing it, an associated action happens.

I have no clue about the possibilities of Gameplaykit. Can anyone tell me an approach using Gameplaykit or whatever Apple has in its magic box of useful tools to make this better than using action walls of SCNPlanes and the physics handler?